# How to backup every Visual C++ build log?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, logging, msbuild, backup

Visual Studio 2012 allows logging MSBuild's output to a file. But this file gets overwritten every time a new build is stated.

How to automatically backup old build logs, to troubleshoot a problematic build even if a new build has been triggered since?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script to copy every build log under a new unique name. For instance, using a timestamp:

```
@Echo off

:: BackupVSLog.bat
:: Locale-independant date adapted from: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html

:: Check if WMIC is available
WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO s_error_no_wmic

:: Check if a log directory was provided
IF %1=="" GOTO s_error_no_dir
Set directory=%1

:: Check if a project name was provided
IF %2=="" GOTO s_error_no_proj
Set project=%2

:: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
      Set _yyyy=%%L
      Set _mm=00%%J
      Set _dd=00%%G
      Set _hour=00%%H
      SET _minute=00%%I
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros
Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%
Set _hour=%_hour:~-2%
Set _minute=%_minute:~-2%

:: Format the date
Set formatteddate=%_yyyy%_%_mm%_%_dd%_%_hour%_%_minute%

:: Copy the provided log, take care of whitespaces
Set "dirnoquotes=%directory:"=%"
Set "projnoquotes=%project:"=%"
Echo Copying "%dirnoquotes%%projnoquotes%.log" to "%dirnoquotes%%projnoquotes%_%formatteddate%.log".
Copy "%dirnoquotes%%projnoquotes%.log" "%dirnoquotes%%projnoquotes%_%formatteddate%.log"
GOTO:EOF

:s_error_no_wmic
Echo Error: WMIC no available.
Echo Requires Windows XP Professional, Vista, Windows 7 or Windows 8.
GOTO:EOF

:s_error_no_dir
Echo Error: Log directory not provided.
Echo Usage: BackupVSLog.bat <VSLogDir> <VSProjectName>
GOTO:EOF

:s_error_no_proj
Echo Error: Project name not provided.
Echo Usage: BackupVSLog.bat <VSLogDir> <VSProjectName>
GOTO:EOF
```

Check that build logging is enabled:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Project Settings > Build logging > **Yes**

[image: Screenshot: enabling build logging]

Chose the logging verbosity:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build log verbosity

[image: Screenshot: setting the log verbosity]

Add a Post-Build Event to the project properties for which build logs should be saved:

> Project properties > Configuration Properties > Build Events > Post-Build Event
>   "C:\Path\To\BackupVSLog.bat" "$(IntermediateOutputPath)" "$(ProjectName)"

[image: Screenshot: setting up the Post-Build Event]